# Dropdown OnSelect and OnChange Actions not firing

Tags: powerapps

I added a textbox called `TextBox1` to my `PowerApps` form.

Then in the `OnSelect` and `OnChange` Actions/Events I add the following code

```
TextBox1.Text="Hallo world"
```

When I run the app and change the select values in the dropdown then the textbox text does not change.

Why does the `OnChange` or `OnSelect` events not get triggered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `TextBox1.Text="Hallo world"` doesn't mean an assignment in PowerApps as it does in many programming languages. Instead, it is a boolean expression, with no side effects (it will compare the text property of the text box with the string `"Hallo world"`.

If you want to use variables, you need to use the [UpdateContext function](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-updatecontext/). In your case, you'd have something like this in the OnChange/OnSelect property of a control:

```
UpdateContext({ myVar: "Hallo world" })
```

And set the Text property of the TextBox1 to `myVar`.

[This doc](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/working-with-variables/) has more information on the use of variables in PowerApps.